# When should I use Development Mode?

Tags: servlets, websphere, rad

I'm using RAD and Websphere Application Server (WAS) 7.0 to develop servlet applications.  I recently saw the Development Mode setting referenced and found it in the Admin console.  However in looking for documentation I can only find [references](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wpdoc/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wp.ent.doc_v615/install/chg_dev_mode.html) to it in context of Portal/Portlet development, and no details of what it actually does to WAS.

When should Development Mode be used and what sort of changes is it making to WAS?

Answer (score 4):

Use it when you value startup time and memory footprint over general application serving performance, for example where you are just using the app server as a testing environment.

It sets the tuning parameters for WebSphere Application Server to values which will produce the fast startup and low(er) memory I mentioned - like a lower maximum heap, for instance. You can always find those parameters and change them if you want to get better general application performance later on.